# Where can I find schematics for the Microchip development kits?

Tags: schematics, microchip

I cannot find schematics on the page of development boards. Is it possible (generally) to get schematics of PIC development boards developed by Microchip?

Answer (score 3):

Schematics will be in the support documents for the particular development board. Every one I've seen has a full schematic (typically in an Appendix).

Comment: OK good, is it possible to also find the board layout file e.g for high speed designs?

Comment: If it's not in the support documents, ask Microchip. Random design files are unlikely to be generally useful because of the many different programs, and Gerber files are only useful if you want to copy exactly what they have done.